# Is addition commutative?

Tags: javascript, numbers

JavaScript's numbers are quirky. I realised that addition is not associative:

```
(-9999999999999999 + 1) + 1 === -9999999999999999 + (1 + 1) // false!
```

What about commutativity? Are there JavaScript numbers `a`, `b` such that

```
typeof a === 'number'
typeof b === 'number'
a + b !== b + a
```

all evaluate to `true` (except `NaN`)?

Comment: most popular programming languages use floating point arithmetic. it's an "approximation". its not associative. not all values can be represented. its a large source of software bugs because programmers often don't understand it.

Comment: Not just about JavaScript, but a bit related: [WAT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXEgk1Hdze0)

Comment: http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/fa07/cs498mjg/notes/floating-point.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a closer look, you will see that 1-9999999999999999 returns -10000000000000000, which is not the result of this operation (should be -9999999999999998)
You are just reaching the limit of floating point precision.
You can see the same effect when doing this : 0.0000000000000001+1 and 0.0000000000000002+1

So the [ecmascript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), numbers should follow the 64-bit format IEEE 754 standard. This corresponds to a 16 digits precision. Which is precisely the size of your numbers.

**EDIT**

Regarding your question about commutativity, here is what the specification states :

*In the remaining cases, where neither an infinity, nor a zero, nor NaN is involved, and the operands have the same sign or have different magnitudes, the sum is computed and rounded to the nearest representable value using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode. If the magnitude is too large to represent, the operation overflows and the result is then an infinity of appropriate sign. The ECMAScript language requires support of gradual underflow as defined by IEEE 754.*

So it should always be commutative, since the sum is computed and then rounded. Any other behaviors would be a bug of your browser.

**EDIT 2**

Even more clear, specification explicitly states (section 11.6.3):

*Addition is a commutative operation, but not always associative.*